# Send to user a copy of contact form to his e-mail

Tags: php, email

this is related to contact form. i am trying to send a copy of email to user also.

so i thought to replace the same function so i repeated `if(!isset($hasError))` second time and changing `$emailTo = $email`

and this is not working. i thing the problem might with the headers... can i write 2 different header tags ?

```
// to me        
    if(!isset($hasError)) {

        $emailTo = 'myemail@website.com';
        $subject = 'Submitted message from '.$name;
        $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
        $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

        $emailSent = true;
    }

//User Copy

if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo  = '$email';
    $subject = 'Thank you for Contacting';

    $body = "Here is your copy of email which you have sent us. \n\nName: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments \n\n Thank you for your email. we will get back to your soon";

    $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

     mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

    $UserEmailSent = true;

}
```

Comment: What are those hashes on the title?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Ah! sorry. i thought these can explain my question easily, just by seeing that line...

Comment: Not at all. We're not used to see that on titles, plus, no need to use *PHP Script* on title, we already see it on the tags. The simpler title is the best.

Comment: I've edited for clarity, hope you like.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown up vote for you :)